# Why 38189 on request

Tags: curl, amadeus

curl -X GET 'https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/activities?latitude=47.052045&longitude=8.305937&radius=10' -H 'Authorization: Bearer dURhumaHEUL4npYGdYfgJs1iF88A'

```
        {
            "errors": [
                    {
                        "code": 38189,
                        "title": "Internal error",
                        "detail": "An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator",
                        "status": 500
                    }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: The error has changed to code `38192` - `"Access token expired"`.

Comment: The API is experiencing some technical issues. The team behind the API is working to fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for the inconveniences!