# Amadeus API - issue with the 'Flight Inspiration Search' API in test mode

Tags: amadeus

I am attempting to get the 'Flight Inspiration Search' API working (https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-inspiration-search/api-reference) and I am receiving the following error:

```
{
    "errors":[{
        "status":500,
        "code":141,
        "title":"SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
        "detail":"Featured Results option is mandatory"
    }]
}
```

I am using the API in test mode and I am passing the required params (also using the data specified on Github: https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md)

Just to confirm, here is what I am passing:

```
$data = array(
    'origin' => 'LON',
    'departureDate' => '2020-10-01',
    'oneWay' => "false",
    'duration' => "3",
    'nonStop' => "false",
    'maxPrice' => "300",
    'viewBy' => 'COUNTRY'
);
```

Please note: I had to put the boolean values in quote marks as it was showing an error when passing as a boolean value.

Where am I going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is the API endpoint I am using
https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations

Comment: There might be a temporary issue with the API since [another similar error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64054757/6367213) has occured relatively recently. Check back in a couple of hours to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Aha thanks for the swift response. I will do so.

Comment: Flight Inspiration Search and Flight Cheapest Date Search are experiencing some technical issues under testing environment. The team behind the APIs is working to fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for the inconveniences!

Comment: Is there an estimated time for fix? I noticed that the API usage still counted even though this wasn't working. Will this be reset? Thanks

Comment: The API is back to normal. Sorry for the inconvinience. We are working on a complete migration of the backend of this 2 APIs (Flight Inspiration Search/Flight Cheapest Date Search) that will bring stability, better data and better response time. The quota will be automatically reset in 3 days (1st of September).

Comment: Thanks. I had to upgrade to live mode and been using it since. I encountered another issue, which I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121899/amadeus-api-issue-with-the-flight-inspiration-search-api-with-origin-on-li