# Amadeus API - issue with the 'Flight Inspiration Search' API with 'origin' on LIVE mode

Tags: amadeus

I am attempting to ping: https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations with origin 'MAN' on LIVE mode but receiving the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"status":500,"code":141,"title":"SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED","detail":"DATA DOMAIN NOT FOUND FOR REQUEST"}]}
```

I understand on TEST mode the origin airports are limited as per documentation on GutHub (https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md), but shouldn't this work on LIVE mode?

Here are the params I am passing:

```
$data = array(
    'origin' => 'MAN',
    'departureDate' => '2020-10-01,2020-10-31',
    'oneWay' => "false",
    'nonStop' => "false",
    'maxPrice' => "300",
    'viewBy' => 'COUNTRY'
);
```

When I change origin to 'LON' or 'LAX', it shows no errors and returns data. Do you know what is wrong? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for reporting the issue. Our technical team is currently investigating and looking for a solution.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Do you have an estimated time when this issue will be resolved?

Comment: any update on this? it's been 11 days since this was posted. It's urgent this is treated with the utmost priority to get it fixed please.

Comment: The city of Manchester as origin is not available in the production environment of this API based on a more limited dataset. We refresh the dataset very frequently and in the near future it will be upgraded with much more data. We suggest to use the [Flight Offers Search API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search) which offers a live coverage with many more origins and destinations.

Comment: A totally useless fake endpoint from Amadeus, I have had a conversation with the support team, their answer was ridiculous. They cache some random data and only that appears even with the production environment.

Comment: @Peter also, the cache is updated once a month. They mentioned they are looking to increase the number of origin airports. However this is based on popularity so if people stop flying to/from from a city, the result will disappear from the cache. Just thought I'd add what I've learned so far.